# Lookup field does not work

Tags: infopath-rules, sharepoint-list

This is my first topic here, so I apologize if I'm not very clear.

I have a form in Infopath 2013, and I created some lookup rules to populate a field.

But this rule only works when I run it in infopath view and does not work when I create the item in the sharepoint list.

Could someone tell me what to do to change this?
There are 3 fields and only one does not work in the sharepoint list.

Answer (score 0):

obviously because infopath rules only work on infopath forms. if you want something to happen outside the infopath form you'll need at least a workflow.